# Not Getting Validation Error for Spring boot application on Postman

Tags: spring-boot, validation, exception, postman

I have created a simple api with validation on Request body. When I am skipping the mandatory field and trying to call the api. On Postman I see only empty response with 400 bad request. If I click on save Response I can see the json response but not here in response body.

[image]

Code for Exception handler is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("timestamp", new Date());
        body.put("status", status.value());

        //Get all errors
        List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
                .getFieldErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        body.put("errors", errors);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);

    }
```

I copied the curl from postman and executed it on terminal and here I can see the validation error response correctly.

[image]

I have gone through some of the existing question posts but still didn't find the reason for this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use exception handler for throwing the exception then you have to create **ExceptionHandlerAdvice Class** and you have to handle the exception. You can refer this code :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

@ExceptionHandler(EmailOrNoAlreadyExistException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseDTO handleEmailOrNoAlreadyExistException(EmailOrNoAlreadyExistException exception) {
        return new ResponseDTO(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()), exception.getMessage(), null);
    }
```

}

And if you want validate using annotation(which is more accurate) then you can refer this code :

You have to use **@valid** annotation to validate the field.

I am giving one reference code :

```
@PostMapping("/addAdmin")
    public ResponseDTO addAdmin(@Valid @RequestBody AddAdminDTO addAdminDTO, Errors errors) throws MessagingException {
        logger.info("AdminController : addAdmin");
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            return new ResponseDTO(StatusCodeEnum.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(), errors.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage(),null);
        }else{
            return adminService.addAdmin(addAdminDTO);
        }
    }
```

In this code you can see that I have used **@Valid** and pre define method **errors.hasErrors()** of **Errors** interface.